# Display information to TV

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, wordpress

At work we got few TVs that we want to use as display TVs to show project related information (Project Schedules/TO DO list from web apps (Buildertrend) and some accounting crystal reports in form of dashboard or as direct crystal reports).

I found a lot of digital signage apps that can display information on to multiple screens from one login.

**Need Help With**
How Can i display information from web apps that requires a login because these cloud based display apps don't have an option to put in login information and I don't have API for data we want to display.
I can export the schedule and To dos from the app into excel. what would be the best way to display this information ? HTML that shows data from excel file and each week we save a new excel file.

any suggestions will be appreciated and if you are expert in display screens maybe we can work together on this for $$.

Comment: I use a [Raspbery Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/) that runs a browser, connected to a tv. Depending on what to show, I write a little node-application that can be run on the Raspberry. With the Raspberry I can also turn on and off the display, play sounds etc...

Comment: You could use a Chromecast to [cast a Chrome browser tab to a TV](https://support.google.com/chromecast/answer/3228332?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Crystal Reports, there are 3rd-party Crystal Reports viewers and schedulers (see list [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html)) that allow you to auto-refresh Crystal reports (including the ability to maximize the use of the screen area by stripping toolbars, etc.) or generate auto-refreshing web dashboards from such reports.